# Custom Profile Center - Exact Target

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

My goal in exact target is to create a custom profile center that my users can go to to update their preferences and subscriptions. In order to do this, I purchased microsites from ET so I can use their AMPScript language as well as the SOAP API.

For starters, I am trying to implement the Sample Profile Center that exact target provides. It can be found here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_a_custom_profile_center_using_ampscript_and_the_soap_api.htm

What I did was I copied the downloaded profile center code into a landing page and published it.

The following error occurred:

The Data Extension name for a LookupOrderedRows function call is invalid. A Data Extension of this name does not exist. Data Extension Name: adminPageInfo Function Call: LOOKUPORDEREDROWS("adminPageInfo",0,"Order asc", "SecretField", "1") Parameter Name: DataExtensionName Parameter Ordinal: 1

If I comment that line out of the code (line 686), the page publishes fine and the data appears correctly based on the user viewing it. It does not however update any of the info if the button is clicked.

Does anyone have insight to this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The Administration Page is looking for a Data Extension called adminPageInfo. It should have a schema something like this:

```
adminPageInfo
-- key (Text - 50)
-- Order (Text - 50)
-- Group (Text - 50)
-- Group Name (Text - 50)
-- Name (Text - 50)
-- Attribute Value (Text - 50)
-- Data Type (Text - 15)
-- Element Value (Text - 50)
-- Required (Boolean)
-- Read Only (Boolean)
-- Limit (Text - 50)
-- Column (Text - 1) OR (Number)
```

Comment: Data extensions must be an added feature because I don't see the option under subscribers? Is that correct? Would this be the reason why my form doesn't send correctly without it?